# NullPointerException al usar getSheet()

Tags: java, apache-poi, nullpointerexception

Estoy tratando de editar un archivo excel con apache poi de la forma siguiente :

```
 public void generarOrdenDePago(Cliente cliente, Periodo periodo, OutputStream outputStream) {

    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("ordenPagoLimpia.xls");
        try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in)) {
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("MySheet");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(15);  //El error sale aquí

            Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("nonononono");

            wb.write(outputStream);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IGenerarOrdenPagoExcelFedex.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

sin embargo, al momento de ejecutar la siguiente linea : `Row row = sheet.createRow(15);`

el sistema me tira un nullPointerException, pero no logró entender por qué.

Esté es el excel que intento editar :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la hoja que quiero editar no se llama "MySheet", sino "reporte", entonces se soluciona de la siguiente forma :

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("reporte");
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias utilizar el indice de la hoja (sheet), empezando siempre en 0.

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

te puedes asegurar que exista mínimo una hoja:

```
if (wb.getNumberOfSheets() > 0) {
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
}
```